# Show records that counts data of a certain column and summing up total amounts

Tags: mysql

I would like to show records from mysql database that counts data of a certain column and summing up the amounts

I have an sql query in which we will focus on MatchID 135

```
SELECT `BetType`,
       `BetAmount`,
       `Payout`
FROM `betdb`
LEFT JOIN `matchdb` ON `betdb`.`MatchID` = `matchdb`.`MatchID`
WHERE `betdb`.`MatchID`=135
```

It returns data like

[image]

I would like to list BetTypes and its Count, BetAmt Total and Payout Total return rows something like

```
BetType       Count     BetAmount Total   Payout Total
Handi           2         60000               950000
Homerun Count   4         10000                 0
Total           6         70000               950000
```

I tried using DISTINCT for BetType but it just returns the first row

Comment: What you want in the updated output could be done with rollup , check my updated answer , this should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT `BetType`,
       count(`BetType`) AS COUNT,
       sum(`BetAmount`) AS BetAmountTotal,
       sum(`Payout`) AS PayoutTotal
FROM `betdb`
LEFT JOIN `matchdb` ON `betdb`.`MatchID` = `matchdb`.`MatchID`
WHERE `betdb`.`MatchID`=135
GROUP BY `BetType`
```

Comment: How about showing the total figures on the last row? Adding the columns of Count, Bet Amount Total, Payout Total

Comment: How can I display a row showing the total of columns like Total           6         70000               950000

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and the relative aggregation [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) and [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) functions here:

```
SELECT
    BetType,
    COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
    SUM(BetAmount) AS 'BetAmount Total',
    SUM(Payout) AS 'Payout Total'
FROM
    betdb
    LEFT JOIN matchdb
        ON betdb.MatchId = matchdb.MatchID
WHERE
    betdb.MatchID = 135
GROUP BY
    BetType
```

This will place each `BetType` into a single row and allow you to apply the aggregates such as `COUNT(*)` to get "how many rows match this `BetType`" or use `SUM(BetAmount)` to add all of the total `BetAmount` values that match the specified `BetType`.

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
  SELECT `BetType`,count(`BetAmount`) count,sum(`BetAmount`) BetAmount_Total ,Sum(`Payout`) Payout_Total
  FROM `betdb` 
  LEFT JOIN `matchdb` ON `betdb`.`MatchID` = `matchdb`.`MatchID` 
  WHERE `betdb`.`MatchID`=135
  GROUP BY `BetType`
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using group by with the aggregate functions and since you want the grand total it needs rollup with some little change in the query.

```
select
ifnull(BetType,'Total') as BetType,
`Count`,
`BetAmount Total`,
`Payout Total`
from(
    select 
    `BetType`,
    count(*) as `Count`,
    sum(BetAmount) as `BetAmount Total`,
    sum(Payout) as `Payout Total`
    from FROM `betdb`
    LEFT JOIN `matchdb` ON `betdb`.`MatchID` = `matchdb`.`MatchID`
    WHERE `betdb`.`MatchID`=135
    group by `BetType` with rollup
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it think this should work:
With COUNT(*), you count the occurrence of BetType for Homrun Count this means 4 times.
With SUM(`BetAmount`) you summarize all content from BetAmount or Payout.
For all other field you need gro group with Group By.

```
SELECT `BetType`,
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(`BetAmount`) as 'BetAmount Total',
    SUM(`Payout`) FROM `betdb` 
LEFT JOIN `matchdb`
    ON `betdb`.`MatchID` = `matchdb`.`MatchID`
WHERE `betdb`.`MatchID`=135 
    GROUP BY 'BetType';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` for counting and `SUM` for adding the values. Something like

`SELECT BetType,
       count(BetTypeAS BetTypeCount,
       sum(BetAmount) AS BetAmountSum,
       sum(PayoutAS PayoutSum
FROM betdb
LEFT JOIN matchdb 
ON betdb.MatchID = matchdb.MatchID
WHERE betdb.MatchID=135
group by BetType`

I have not tested this, but it will surely give you a starting point.