# Sql query to sum up total of columns previously used aggregate function

Tags: mysql

From this post, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910094/show-records-that-counts-data-of-a-certain-column-and-summing-up-total-amounts)

I would like to improve the query

```
SELECT `BetType`,
   count(`BetType`) AS COUNT,
   sum(`BetAmount`) AS BetAmountTotal,
   sum(`Payout`) AS PayoutTotal
FROM `betdb`
LEFT JOIN `matchdb` ON `betdb`.`MatchID` = `matchdb`.`MatchID`
WHERE `betdb`.`MatchID`=135
GROUP BY `BetType`
```

thanks to Sadikhasan, who helped on this query

I would like to add another row showing the totals of the columns

```
BetType       Count     BetAmount Total   Payout Total
Handi           2         60000               950000
Homerun Count   4         10000                 0
Total           6         70000               950000
```

this seems to be needing another SELECT statement but how would I put another row explicitly showing the "Total" string and getting the sum of the previously used columns with Aggregate Functions?

Comment: Try to use union in your query.

Comment: rollup variant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433885/how-do-i-add-a-total-as-the-last-row-in-my-sql

Comment: union variant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232306/mysql-get-total-in-last-row-of-mysql-result

Comment: @setsuna what output you are expecting

Comment: from the query above, I can get all the result except the Total           6         70000               950000 part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier to `GROUP BY`, which will give you another row with totals, but the column you group on (BetType) will show `NULL` for that row. But nothing stops you from using [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html) to replace that `NULL` with 'Total' string.

```
SELECT COALESCE(`BetType`,'Total') AS BetType,
   COUNT(*) AS `Count`,
   sum(BetAmount) AS BetAmountTotal,
   sum(Payout) AS PayoutTotal
FROM betdb
WHERE betdb.MatchID=135
GROUP BY BetType WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: woh quite complicated sql query! Thank you! I'm learning many things here! Thank you very much